# How to retrieve a List of Lists of strings that are not null or whitespace from a DataGridView using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

My question of course is exactly what my title says it is. I am still very new to linq. But its usefulness necessitates for me to learn it.

I have a query that is a work in progress. I feel I am almost there but I am getting null list even though there is plenty of stuff in the DataGridView named DataView.

Here is my query so far.

```
     List<List<string>> newData = new List<List<string>>();
     newData =  DataView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Select(row => row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
            .Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString())
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            .ToList()
          .ToList()) as List<List<string>>;
```

I was basing my query loosely on what I saw [here on an MSDN forum.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a34acd0-e1d4-450b-b6fa-ad9baeac8dd0/2d-string-array-from-datatable-using-linq?forum=csharplanguage)

Comment: first, remove `as List<List<string>>`, then replace `newData = ...` with `var something = ...` to see what your expression return

Comment: So when I do that I see that the correct stuff is in the var. But if I try to cast the var to a List<List<string> it leaves me with an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your LINQ statement is returning is actually an `IEnumerable<List<string>>`.

When you cast the result using `as List<List<string>>`, you end up with `null`... because the result is not actually that type.

Currently you've got this, which is redundant:

```
.ToList().ToList()
```

Modify your LINQ statement accordingly:

```
List<List<string>> newData =
    dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                 .Select(row => row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
                                   .Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString())
                                   .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                                   .ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. It seems my parenthesis were misplaced.